# Como puedo optimizar este codigo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo 5 divs y si entro a uno de esos se pinta la pantalla del color del div y si salgo se pinta de blanco, como puedo optimizar el codigo en donde sea un bloque de codigo para esos 5 divs y que detecte el div seleccionado y pinte la pantalla de blanco.
Adjunto mi código:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body onmousemove="coordenadas(event)">
    <div id="cuadrado1"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado2"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado3"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado4"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado5"></div>
    <div id="posicion">Posicion del raton</div>
    <div>
        <p>Paleta de Colores: </p>
        <input type="color" name="paleta" id="paleta">
        <br />
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#cuadrado1{
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cuadrado2{
    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cuadrado3{
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cuadrado4{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cuadrado5{
    background-color:orange;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
const cuadrado1 = document.querySelector('#cuadrado1');
const cuadrado2 = document.querySelector('#cuadrado2');
const cuadrado3 = document.querySelector('#cuadrado3');
const cuadrado4 = document.querySelector('#cuadrado4');
const cuadrado5 = document.querySelector('#cuadrado5');
const posicion = document.querySelector('#posicion');
const cuerpo = document.querySelector('body');
const paleta = document.querySelector('#paleta');

const coordenadas = event => {
    const {clientX, clientY} = event;
    let x = clientX;
    let y = clientY;
    posicion.innerHTML = `Coordenadas en X: ${x}, Coordenadas en Y: ${y}`;
}

paleta.addEventListener('input', e => {
    const {target: {value}} = e;
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = value;
});

cuadrado1.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "green";
})
cuadrado1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
cuadrado2.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "blue";
})
cuadrado2.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
cuadrado3.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "red";
})
cuadrado3.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
cuadrado4.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
})
cuadrado4.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
cuadrado5.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "orange";
})
cuadrado5.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    const {style} = cuerpo;
    style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
```

Comment: Pon en el título _qué estás buscando hacer_. Suena a que querés _modificar_ o _corregir_ tu código (optimizarlo sería _mejorarlo_)

Comment: Molesta que aqui siempre aunque seas claro pidan corregir la pregunta y al final nadie apoya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para optimizar tu script hagamos primero un par de ajustes en tu HTML y CSS.

Antes de nada vamos a quitar el onmousemove de la etiqueta body, ya que en ese punto aún no se ha cargado el javascript. Luego añadiremos el listener en el script. Después asignemos una clase CSS `cuadrado` a todos los cuadrados.

**HTML**

```html
<!-- He omitido el HEAD -->
<body>
    <div id="cuadrado1" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado2" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado3" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado4" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado5" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="posicion">Posicion del raton</div>
    <div>
        <p>Paleta de Colores: </p>
        <input type="color" name="paleta" id="paleta">
        <br />
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

Modifiquemos el CSS para que se apliquen los estilos comunes basándonos en la clase `cuadrado` y las diferencias basándonos en los ID:

```css
.cuadrado{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cuadrado1{
    background-color:green;
}
#cuadrado2{
    background-color:blue;
}
#cuadrado3{
    background-color:red;
}
#cuadrado4{
    background-color:yellow;
}
#cuadrado5{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

**Javascript**

Vayamos ahora poco a poco con el script.

Añadamos el listener al body para la detección de la posición del usuario:

```javascript
// dado que tenemos lo siguiente
const posicion = document.querySelector('#posicion');
const cuerpo = document.querySelector('body');

// podemos hacer esto directamente
cuerpo.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    posicion.innerHTML = `Coordenadas en X: ${event.clientX}, Coordenadas en Y: ${event.clientY}`;
});
```

Añadamos el listener ahora al input del color para que cambie el color de fondo. Como añadido he hecho que establezca un atributo del elemento como true si el usuario ha modificado el valor por defecto:

```javascript
// tenemos la variable paleta definida con
const paleta = document.querySelector('#paleta');

// hagamos que se establezca el color del input como color de fondo
// a la vez asignamos true a un atributo "changed" para saber que ha habido modificación del valor
paleta.addEventListener('input', e => {
  paleta.setAttribute('changed', true);
  cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = paleta.value;
});
```

Y ahora añadimos los listener a los cuadrados. Para ello no es necesario ir uno por uno, podemos seleccionar todos con `querySelectorAll` para luego con `foreach` asociar los `eventListener`. En ese `foreach` podemos acceder al color del cuadrado actual con `window.getComputedStyle(cuadrado).backgroundColor`.

En el evento `mouseleave` comprobaremos si existe un atributo `changed` en el `input` de color. En caso de existir estableceremos como color de fondo el seleccionado en la paleta. En caso contrario pondremos `'white'`.

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll('.cuadrado').forEach((cuadrado) => {
  cuadrado.addEventListener('mouseenter', (c) => {
    cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(cuadrado).backgroundColor;
  });
  cuadrado.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = ((paleta.getAttribute('changed'))?paleta.value:'white');
  })
});
```

**JS Completo**

```javascript
const posicion = document.querySelector('#posicion');
const cuerpo = document.querySelector('body');
const paleta = document.querySelector('#paleta');

cuerpo.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    posicion.innerHTML = `Coordenadas en X: ${event.clientX}, Coordenadas en Y: ${event.clientY}`;
});

paleta.addEventListener('input', e => {
  paleta.setAttribute('changed', true);
  cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = paleta.value;
});

document.querySelectorAll('.cuadrado').forEach((cuadrado) => {
  cuadrado.addEventListener('mouseenter', (c) => {
    cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(cuadrado).backgroundColor;
  });
  cuadrado.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = ((paleta.getAttribute('changed'))?paleta.value:'white');
  })
})
```

---

**Ejemplo completo**

Aquí tienes un snippet ejecutable con mi alternativa a tu código

```js
const posicion = document.querySelector('#posicion');
const cuerpo = document.querySelector('body');
const paleta = document.querySelector('#paleta');

cuerpo.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    posicion.innerHTML = `Coordenadas en X: ${event.clientX}, Coordenadas en Y: ${event.clientY}`;
});

paleta.addEventListener('input', e => {
  paleta.setAttribute('changed', true);
  cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = paleta.value;
});

document.querySelectorAll('.cuadrado').forEach((cuadrado) => {
  cuadrado.addEventListener('mouseenter', (c) => {
    cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(cuadrado).backgroundColor;
  });
  cuadrado.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = ((paleta.getAttribute('changed'))?paleta.value:'white');
  })
})
```

```css
.cuadrado{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cuadrado1{
    background-color:green;
}
#cuadrado2{
    background-color:blue;
}
#cuadrado3{
    background-color:red;
}
#cuadrado4{
    background-color:yellow;
}
#cuadrado5{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="cuadrado1" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado2" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado3" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado4" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="cuadrado5" class="cuadrado"></div>
    <div id="posicion">Posicion del raton</div>
    <div>
        <p>Paleta de Colores: </p>
        <input type="color" name="paleta" id="paleta">
        <br />
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Pues primero podrias generar una clase para evitar repetir el selector por cada elemento, de tal manera que hagas uno solo y con ese le agregues los eventos. Despues puedes Generar un Array en Javascript, con el valor de los colores, y asignarle un attributo a  cada uno de los divs para saber que posicion dentro de ese array pertenecen.

```
<div class="cuadrados" id="cuadrado1" data-color = 1></div>
<div class="cuadrados" id="cuadrado2" data-color = 2></div>
<div class="cuadrados" id="cuadrado3" data-color = 3></div>
<div class="cuadrados" id="cuadrado4" data-color = 4></div>
<div class="cuadrados" id="cuadrado5" data-color = 5></div>
```

Y en el Javascript, Hacer un selector a cuadrados y recorrerlo agregando los eventos a cada elemento.

```
const colors = ["white","green","blue","red","yellow","orange"];
const cuadrados = document.querySelectorAll('.cuadrados');
cuadrados.forEach((cuadro) => {
  cuadro.addEventListener('mouseenter', (element) => {
      // Cuando caiga aqui el evento, tomar el dataset-color para tomar
      // el valor de esa posicion en colors[]
      cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = colors[element.target.dataset.color];
  })
  cuadro.addEventListener('mouseleave', (element) => {
      // Resetear el color a la posicion 0 de colors[] que es "white"
      cuerpo.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
  })
})
```